# Prove that if a differential equation $f$ is separable, then $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y} \ln |f|=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, partial-derivative

Prove that if the differential equation
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = f(x, y)$$

is separable, then for all $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) \neq 0$,

$$ \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y} \ln |f|=0$$

I tried to approach this by starting with
$$ \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y} \ln |f|= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \ln |f| = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \ln |f|}{\partial f} \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \ln |f|}{\partial f} f(x, y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{f(x, y)}{ f} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} 1 = 0$$

However, I am not sure if this proof is valid. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Edit: $$ \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y} \ln |f|= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (\ln |M(x)| - \ln |N(y)|) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (0- \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\ln |M(x)| - \ln |N(y)|)) =0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a differential equation is separable then $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)=\frac{M(x)}{N(y)}$.

$\ln|f(x,y)|=\ln|M(x)|-\ln|N(y)|$

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \big[\ln|M(x)|-\ln|N(y)| \big] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg[0-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big[\ln|N(y)|\big]\bigg]=0 $ because $M(x)$ and $N(y)$ are functions of $x$ and $y$ strictly.

Comment: Can you please check my edit to see that I understood your hint correctly?

Comment: I think I clarified it in my edit as well, essentially, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} [ln|N(y)|] $ is still just a function of $y$ thus treated as a constant throught partial diff by $x$

Comment: uhm also $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} [ln|N(y)|]$ is not necessarily equal to $\frac{1}{N(y)}$, implicit differentiation still applies, it would be something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[N(y)]\frac{1}{N(y)}$ take $N(y) = y^2$ for example

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about how you concluded $ \frac{ \partial}{ \partial x} \frac { \partial {\ln |N(y)|}} { \partial y} = 0$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: $N(y)$ is strictly a function of $y$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} [ln|N(y)|] $ is also strictly a function of $y$ because we are differentiating with respect to $y$ only, from there, partial differentiation with respect to $x$ of a function of $y$ strictly is like taking the derivative of a constant, because any variable other than $x$ is treated like a constant. For example $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} [y^3 + 4y^2 +3 - sin(y)] = 0$, there is no variable $x$.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Nice answer, +1 to you.